# ZF2 application autoload files

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've been experimenting with integrating ZF2 with Doctrine 2 using SpiffyDoctrine libraries.

The docs suggest dropping a module.spiffy_doctrine_orm.config.php into config/autoload for the Application. However when I do this I am getting an error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ~/zf2tutorial-doc/config/autoload/module.spiffy_doctrine_orm.config.php:1) in ~/zf2/library/Zend/Http/PhpEnvironment/Response.php on line 40
```

However if I removed this file and drop the contents of it into either the local.config.php (which seems a good place for database login details) or global.config.php then there isn't a problem.

My question is, why this is so? I can't find anything is the ZF2 docs that explains this autoload folder other than all files are auto run.

Comment: This looks like some random characters have made it before that '<?php'. You might check escaped characters (e.g. UTF8-specific ones) as well. About the autoload: keep in mind this is a early beta and documentation is at best rudimentary. You really should like to explore the zf-code by yourself if you want to use it (at this stage).

Comment: Wow! You're right there was a space there. If you get time add that as an answer. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some random characters have made it before that `<?php`. You might check escaped characters (e.g. UTF8-specific ones) as well.

The folder itself is thought of as a place for application specific configuration while the other config files within the module folders are for module specific configuration. So modules provide a configuration which you can overwrite in that folder for application specific needs.